# PHP OOP - isset and filesize dosen't work after upload form

Tags: php, isset

i don't know if the code is right but MAX FILE SIZE don't work

and don't che if file exist or not, maybe i've wrong implemented
isset or there are something in the code.

p.s. give me this error:

Notice: Undefined variable: content in ecc../ecc. on line 23

Notice: Undefined variable: fp in ecc../ecc. on line 24

here is the code:

```
<?php
interface ICheckImage {

         public function checkImage();

}           
abstract class ACheckImage implements ICheckImage {

         public $fileName;
         public $tmpName;
         public $filesSize;
         public $fileType;
         public $fp;
         public $conent;
         protected $mysqli; 

         public function __construct(){

             $this->fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
             $this->tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
             $this->filesSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
             $this->fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];
             $this->content = $content;
             $this->fp = $fp;
             $this->mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','root','test');

            }
    }           
class Check extends ACheckImage {

         public function checkImage(){

             if(isset($_POST['upload']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0){

                 $this->fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
                 $this->tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
                 $this->filesSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
                 $this->fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

                 $this->fp      = fopen($this->tmpName, 'r');
                 $this->content = fread($this->fp, filesize($this->tmpName));
                 $this->content = addslashes($this->content);
                 fclose($this->fp);

                 if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc()){

                     $this->fileName = addslashes($this->fileName);

                    }

                 if ($this->mysqli->query("INSERT INTO upload_images (name, size, type, content ) ".
                      "VALUES ('$this->fileName', '$this->filesSize', '$this->fileType', '$this->content')")){

                         echo "Upload avvenuto &nbsp";

                    }else{

                         echo "Errore &nbsp" . $this->mysqli->error; 

                        }   
                }
            }           
    }

$form = new Check();
$form->checkImage();    

?>
```

Comment: `$this->content = $content; //$content not defined local variable
             $this->fp = $fp; //$content not defined local variable`

Comment: I don't get one thing. Error message is very self-explanatory. Even line number is given. Why is it so hard to debug **your own code**?

Comment: yes but is not this the problem..thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you defining $content and $fp variables that you are passing to the __construct() in ACheckImage class?

If you really want to set empty values for the variables, try changing this:

```
<?php
abstract class ACheckImage implements ICheckImage {

     public $fileName;
     public $tmpName;
     public $filesSize;
     public $fileType;
     public $fp;
     public $conent;
     protected $mysqli; 

     public function __construct(){

       if (count($_FILES)>0) {
         $this->fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
         $this->tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
         $this->filesSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
         $this->fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];
         $this->content = '';
         $this->fp = '';
         $this->mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','root','test');
       }

     }

}
?>
```

Comment: thanks, but one more question..
if i click upload in form and don't have selected any file the result is a blank page with no errors..why?

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on in PHP? Usually, I make some verifications if array have values or not. If not it will just continue on the code. Try to make an if statement like if (count($_FILES) > 0). Edited my code.

Answer (score 0):

One of your issues is this:

```
         public $conent;
```

You are referring to it (on line 23) as `$this->content`, and then setting it equal to an undefined local variable `$content`

The same issue for `$this->fp`.  At that point in your constructor, you have not defined what the local variable `$fp` is, so how is PHP supposed to know?  Perhaps you're supposed to pass it in to the constructor?

Also, if I remember correctly, if the `MAX_FILE_SIZE` is violated, then the file will not exist on the server and the `$_FILES` array will not be populated.